# Netlogo - Create an Action Every 60 Ticks

Tags: netlogo

I have a microorganism that is eating 160 lettuce molecules. I want the microorganism to only eat one of the lettuce molecules every 60 ticks. How do I write that code in? Below is the code for the microorganism eating the lettuce molecules. Thanks in advance!

```
to go
  ask microorganisms [
    move
    let food one-of lettuces-here
    if food != nobody [
      ask food [ die ]
    ]
    ]
    tick

end

to move
  set lettuce_index 1
  loop [
    ifelse lettuce lettuce_index != nobody [
      face lettuce lettuce_index
      fd 1
      stop
    ]
    [
      set lettuce_index lettuce_index + 1
    ]
  ]

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't work out what your move procedure is supposed to do. However, I don't think that's important to solve the 'only do this every 60 ticks' problem. The easiest way is to use the `mod` primitive. So put your entire eating of food inside an `if` condition with `if ticks mod 60 = 0 [ ]`